# This contact us page cannot be fixed by the left and right border of parent div

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

[image]

```
<div class="col s1 m-5" style="background-color: white">
    <div id="gd1" style="background-color: aqua;width: 100%;align-items: center;height: 20%;border-radius: 1% 1% 0 0;margin: 0;text-align: center;color: white;;">
      <br>  
      <h4>
        CONTECT US 3
      </h4>
      <i class="fa fa-facebook m-3"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-twitter m-3"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-google m-3"></i>
    </div>
    <input type="text" value="Your Name" name="Phone"  class="inpb"><br>
    <input type="text" name="E-mail" value="Your Mail"  class="inpb"><br><br><br><br><br>
    <textarea name="" id="" class="inpb" cols="20" rows="1" style="border-top: 1px solid;border-bottom: 0px;">Massege</textarea>
    <button id="gd1" class="bt1 m-5 p-1" style="width: 80px;float: right;" > SEND</button>
  </div>
```

Using Css, Bootstrap 5.
This Contact us page cannot be fix by left and right boarder of parent div. How to fix it?
I want to cover 100% area of parent div.

Comment: If you use your browser's devtools inspect facility you should be able to see exactly what/where is setting the margins of that element (or positioning it).

Comment: Add position: relative . For Example  : <div class="col s1 m-5" style="background-color: white; position: relative;"> Hope this work fine !!

Answer (score 0):

You may need to share through a CodPen, but it looks like you have "m-5" added to your parent div. Remove that as it's a default class from Bootstrap calling margin around the parent. More information can be found here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/

Hope this helps!